# How to locate an element in new page using xpath after navigating to new page from old one in selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I was trying to automate flipkart Login and adding product to cart. whenever i clicked on product its navigating to new page and not able to locate specified element(add to cart button) in new page. please help...The code i written is as follows...

webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//img[contains(@alt,'APPLE iPhone SE (Black, 64 GB)')]")).Click();//clicked on product
webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@class='_2KpZ6l _2U9uOA _3v1-ww']")).Click();//navigating to new page

Answer (score 0):

When a new tab is opened you should switch the Selenium driver focus to the new tab in order to access the elements there.
This can be done as following:

```cs
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());
```

When finished with that tab you will wish to close that tab and switch back to the first tab.
This can be done with

```cs
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandlesLast()).Close(); // close the last tab
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles[0]); // get back to the first tab
```